# Should I send another application after two weeks?

Tags: job-offer

I need some help. 
I'm 26 and I've applied two weeks ago for a position in a small company (40 people) writing directly to the hiring manager. I had the 90% of the requirements, with the exception of the language, they were looking for someone fluent in French and English (I'm only in English), but I decided to give a try (because I work in IT). They didn't reply to me, neither to say thanks.
Today they advertised another position, the same HR manager, and this one fits 100% with me, because they want someone fluent only in English and I've all the other requirements.

I would like to apply, but I don't want to seem "desperate", that I'm applying for another job to the same guy and company after 2 weeks. 
The point is, should I sent him another application or not? if yes how can I justify the previous one? Because writing "oh sorry I didn't read that you were looking someone proficient in French" sound that I even didn't read the ad...

thanks!

Comment: Do the ads list any contact information of the HR manager?

Comment: Hi thanks, why?
Not on the website, the email address is the generic one. Just on linkedin, if you do a deep search, you find the HR guy. Last time I wrote his name inside "dear hisname" now (ten min ago) I used a generic "dear hiring manager". Hope it's gonna work.

Comment: Well, if they list a phone number "in case you have any question", you could try to call them, ask the things you want to know (prepare this well). They might pick you out of the pile easier.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely you should send in another application for the new job listing.  It is perfectly normal for someone to send in multiple job applications to a company, if that company has multiple jobs that the person is interested in.  There is nothing desperate about that.

The hiring manager probably receives a lot of applications for each job listing, so he probably won't even remember that you applied for the previous position.  You don't need to mention that you already applied for the other position.

Comment: Thanks. But it's a small company, I saw from linkedin that only 10 people apply in 25 days for the previous position(that is still active!), so I think he remember about my cv....
So you would anyway write without mention anything?

Comment: @Octopus Sure.  Even if he remembers that you applied for the previous position, it's not a big deal.  You should send in an application for each position that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

> they were looking someone fluent in French and English (I'm only in English), but I decided to gave a try

- they were looking for someone
- to give it a try

Best let someone with better english skills check your application before sending it in. And yes, send it in! You are currently looking for a job, and it shows you are taking it serious. There's nothing desperate about that.

Would be maybe weird if you now skip 2-3 months of job offers and then reappear to another one, but even then, send it in!

Comment: Thanks, also for pointing out the mistakes. I will send it in then!